# HTML no me detecta archivo CSS

Tags: html, css

no se porqué me está ocurriendo esto. Acabo de crear un nuevo archivo HTML y lo he vinculado con la hoja de estilos CSS, ambos codigos están vacios menos un div que he creado. La cosa es que HTML no me detecta el CSS. Está estructurado así:

html
---   index.html
---   styles.css

Sin embargo si el codigo del CSS lo copio dentro del html si me lo coge. Los codigos de ambos ficheros son estos.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Iniciar sesión</title>
    <link src="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="formulario1">
        Ejemplo 1
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

```css
.formulario1 {
    background-color: #040404;
    margin: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    font-size: 34sp;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Lo pregunto por aquí por que entiendo que no es un problema de ficheros sino que hay algo más, si alguien lo sabe se lo agradezco de adelantado.

Edito: no es tema de caché ni nada del navegador.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es que en lugar de usar el atributo `href` estas usando `src`.

Importa tu hoja de estilos asi:

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Y ya. Probado en https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-html-css-js-sandbox-forked-ikestc

> Podes leer mas en https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: Muchas gracias era eso, hace mucho que no tocaba html y css esto es nuevo? acabo de revisar codigos antiguos que tenia de hace 4 años aprox y con src me funcionaba. Gracias!

Comment: @AdriaFernandez si, a mi me llamo la atencion lo mismo, hace mucho tiempo que no traigo CSS de esa forma, y buscando en https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link veo que el atributo SRC directamente ya no existe para la etiqueta link, pero tambien veo preguntas de 2017 en este sitio donde ya tenian el atributo href. Debe ser esa tipica caracteristica que la agregan, te dicen "deja de usar SRC porque va a estar deprecado en X años", sirven las dos entonces no le damos bola, y despues nuestros sitios dejan de funcionar jaja